# Terrible performance in desktop at 4K

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, performance

i'm running ubuntu 14.04, is it a known problem to have bad performance compared to windows? This is my setup:

2x nvidia gtx970

intel i7 5820K

monitor: Samsung U28D590

nvidia drivers: 343.22

one gpu is idling at 2% usage

and the cpu is about 15% on each core.

running minecraft is impossible, even on 1920x1080, with just over 10 fps.

when i have my monitor set to 4k everything is really slow, even the start/searchbar.

Any way i could fix this, or is it a driver problem?

Comment: Nividia has always hated on anything other than Windows

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! 3840 x 2160 and Performance in the same breath? I'm not sure what I would expect from 8,294,400 pixels. Extreme clarity I suppose for working on say 8Mpixel images. I wouldn't even attempt gaming with a monitor with that native resolution.

Comment: After two years I am having a similar issue.

Comment: Just to remind anyone who seeks for this answer.
The performance is terrible even on Windows 10 for 4K on these cards. The GTX970 is simply not powerful enough to handle such a high resolution, even with full hardware acceleration is enabled, like in Windows 10 so, there is nothing we can do about it. You need a bigger and more powerful card for fluid 4K desktop, be it ubuntu or windows.

Comment: This is not true, performance on windows is perfect. I have a GTX 965M/Intel® HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2) combination. On Windows, everythings works fine and fast. On Ubuntu 16.04, the desktop is slow, websites render slow, everything is a bit unsmooth. (4k)
I'm using the 387.34 driver from nVidia.
I intalled https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/nvidia-settings/, so I can switch between both GPUs. Both are slow in 4k. On Windows, both are perfectly fast.
Any more ideas on how to fix that are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as that is a fairly new GPU I would try with the latest 346 Nvidia drivers. You can download them directly from http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html or use the PPA https://launchpad.net/~mamarley/+archive/ubuntu/nvidia

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have 2 brand new graphic cards :) (the drivers don't support them yet) maybe you should check that you have selected the right driver and that this one is running or maybe just run your system with one graphic card and look how your performance changes.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your answer. Can you clarify? I can get past most of the spelling errors, but I can't wrap my head around "the driver arend so far"

Comment: because the chipset is new must first develop a new driver . there are things like 4k not so important you know what i mean (i hope so) :D